# multiple servers that are also clients - communacation in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I am using sockets in JAVA and I have 3 Servers that are Clients are the same time. I want them to exchange some information.

This is what I want to create:
[image: Three peer machines]

**The input should be something like this:**

Server started at:/172.16.2.22:8080
info for first,
info for second,
info for third,

Server started at:/172.16.2.22:8081
info for first,
info for second,
info for third,

Server started at:/172.16.2.22:8082
info for first,
info for second, 
info for third,

But for some reason it shows only the info of the client that is currently a server as well.

**So I get this result:**

Server started at:/172.16.2.22:8080
info for first

Server started at:/172.16.2.22:8081
info for second

Server started at:/172.16.2.22:8082
info for third

This is how I initiate my code, the **Server**:

```
    private void startServer() {

    ServerSocket providerSocket = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(this.serv.getIP());
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serv.getPort(), 50, addr);
        System.out.println("ServThread started at:" + addr + ":" + this.serv.getPort());


        // create a new thread object
        Thread t = new ClientHandler(providerSocket);

        // Invoking the start() method
        t.start();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

This is the **ClientHandler** that I am using for **threads**:

```
    class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    final ServerSocket s;

    // Constructor
    public ClientHandler(ServerSocket s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run() {

        Socket s = null;
        try {
            s = this.s.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                // receive the answer from client


                String line = null;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And finally my **Clients**, that are also the servers. I am using a for loop to read a txt with all the IP,PORTS of my servers:

```
    private void startSender() {

    for (MyServers servs : ServersTXT.fetchTXTofServers()) {
        BufferedWriter out;
        try (Socket s = new Socket(servs .getIP(), servs .getPort())) {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
            out.write(servs.info());
            out.newLine();
            out.flush();
        } catch (ConnectException err) {
            // Connection failed because not all servers on the txt are up
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like your `ClientHandler` is wrong.  Given your architecture, I think you need to spawn one thread per connection (per each time `accept()` returns a new connection).  Otherwise, your client handler just accepts the first connection, then goes to a permanent `while(true)` loop and never looks for a second client.  Try testing just that: one server, connect multiple clients to it.  Can you do that?

Comment: If each of your "Client/Server" entities is a single thread, then it will be very easy for you to create a deadlock situation (e.g., the red thread is waiting for the black thread to respond, but the black thread can't respond because it is waiting for the green thread, and the green thread can't respond because it is waiting for the red thread.) I would be looking for a way to change the architecture and break that dependency cycle.

Comment: @markspace I believe the issue is on the startSender part, ti does not send to more than one participants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some time to understand your architecture and I managed to figure out which was the problem. The ClientHandler is indeed wrong because the *connection.accept()* part is outside the while loop and the connections get lost. The architecture you are trying to achieve has the following rule. Once I get a connection, spawn a thread to handle this connection not just for one time, but continuously. The above code is going to fix your problem as long as you place it **inside** the run function at the **ClientHandler thread**.

```
ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection;
InetAddress addr;
try {
    addr = InetAddress.getByName(this.broker.getIP());
    providerSocket = new ServerSocket(this.broker.getPort(), 50, addr);
    while (true) {
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println(n.readUTF());
        in.close();
        out.close();
        connection.close();
    }
} catch (Exception err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, at the sender part, at the try block, you try to execute the code at parenthesis, usually try blocks have no parentheses, in my code I removed it.